# How to acces a method outside of an EventListener? (SAPUI5)

Tags: scope, this, sapui5

I got an MenuItem like this:

```js
new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
    text: "ID",
    submenu: new sap.ui.unified.Menu({
        items: [this.oIdMenuButton = new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
            text: "IDs anzeigen/ausblenden",
            icon: "resources/images/check.png",
            select: this._onShowHideIdRequest
        })]
    })
})
```

And an EventListener like this:

```js
_onShowHideIdRequest: function (oControlEvent) {

}
```

This code is inside a component. The problem that now occurs is this: I can't access the component as itself. Because when I call `this.` I access the MenuItem, which fired the Event. How can I access methods outside of this EventListener method? I know that there is `sap.ui.getCore().byId(id)` but normally I don't know the id of my component. And also I can't store the id, because, I can't access the id inside the EventHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify call to `_onShowHideIdRequest` with this line of code, it will give access to Component.

```
this._onShowHideIdRequest.bind(this);
```

Comment: I don't know, what you mean with this. When I ´log´ the ´this´ object inside my event, then there is, as before, the MenuItem logged ...

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question let me modify my answer

Comment: Welcome! kindly accept the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a wide amount of arguments to `select` [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.MenuItemBase.html#constructor)

```js
// a function that will be called
function
// same as above
[ function ]
// the function will be called, value of this is the context-object
[ function, context ]
// the function will be called, the value of this is the context-object, the data will be passed to the function as argument
[ data, function, object ]
```

example:

```js
var ctx = {foo: "bar"};
new MenuItem({
    select: [
        function () {
            console.log(this.foo);
        }, ctx
    ]
});
```

should result in a logged "bar"